# Aggregate interpolated data at county level with R

Tags: r, interpolation, sf, aggregation, gstat

The raw data is at the state level and I would like to go down to the county level. To do this, I first adjusted the data to county level and then interpolated it.

The raw data on state level looks like this: **object name "df.sf"**

```
Simple feature collection with 16 features and 5 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 848097.3 ymin: 2281812 xmax: 1485685 ymax: 3136914
Projected CRS: NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II + NGF Lallemand height
First 10 features:
   CC_1    cty_area psych_dis      dpr      BMI
1     8 36095215398  19.07783 12.00708 26.07741
2     9 70643514694  19.79458 12.37472 25.63492
3    11   900908400  20.43846 12.49231 25.13092
4    12 29954144448  20.20175 12.37719 26.61934
5     4   404969822  18.00000 11.33333 25.32944
6     2   747005892  18.23529 11.80392 24.56922
7     6 21203879353  19.52273 12.06364 25.83914
8    13 23736584551  21.46269 13.32836 26.73993
9     3 48207855936  20.56610 12.80000 25.68827
10    5 34345207798  19.95376 12.45279 26.12742
                         geometry
1  MULTIPOLYGON (((1077800 231...
2  MULTIPOLYGON (((1156417 230...
3  MULTIPOLYGON (((1338714 287...
4  MULTIPOLYGON (((1279750 284...
5  MULTIPOLYGON (((1029656 291...
6  MULTIPOLYGON (((1125077 297...
7  MULTIPOLYGON (((1058410 253...
8  MULTIPOLYGON (((1203756 304...
9  MULTIPOLYGON (((894800.9 29...
10 MULTIPOLYGON (((1004934 264...
```

The raw data adjusted at the county level is as follows: **object name "bl.lk"**

```
Simple feature collection with 401 features and 4 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 848080 ymin: 2281823 xmax: 1485607 ymax: 3136923
Projected CRS: NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II + NGF Lallemand height
First 10 features:
    AGS      BMI      dpr psych_dis                       geometry
1  1001 26.68627 11.61818  19.20000 MULTIPOLYGON (((1064024 311...
2  1002 26.68627 11.61818  19.20000 MULTIPOLYGON (((1111437 307...
3  1003 26.68662 11.62940  19.21484 MULTIPOLYGON (((1161867 303...
4  1004 26.68627 11.61818  19.20000 MULTIPOLYGON (((1102924 304...
5  1051 26.68627 11.61818  19.20000 MULTIPOLYGON (((1058696 302...
6  1053 26.68471 11.62609  19.20966 MULTIPOLYGON (((1165074 298...
7  1054 26.68627 11.61818  19.20000 MULTIPOLYGON (((1003984 308...
8  1055 26.68627 11.61818  19.20000 MULTIPOLYGON (((1149981 305...
9  1056 26.67913 11.61881  19.19674 MULTIPOLYGON (((1102964 298...
10 1057 26.68627 11.61818  19.20000 MULTIPOLYGON (((1130439 307...
```

This is the plot of both:

[image]

After this, I made a grid of 10x10 km and adjusted it to the borders of Germany:

**object name "grid"**

```
Simple feature collection with 3885 features and 0 fields
Geometry type: GEOMETRY
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 848097.3 ymin: 2281812 xmax: 1485685 ymax: 3136914
Projected CRS: NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II + NGF Lallemand height
First 10 features:
                             grid
1  POLYGON ((1186108 2291812, ...
2  POLYGON ((1198097 2291812, ...
3  POLYGON ((1198097 2291812, ...
4  POLYGON ((998097.3 2301812,...
5  MULTIPOLYGON (((1008097 230...
6  MULTIPOLYGON (((1014797 230...
7  POLYGON ((1028097 2301812, ...
8  POLYGON ((1028097 2301812, ...
9  MULTIPOLYGON (((1185004 229...
10 POLYGON ((1188097 2301812, ...
```

grid plot:

[image]

After fitting my variogram model using a spherical model, I interpolated my data on the new grid. Therefore I used the package "gstat".

This is my variogram plot:

[image]

I used the ordinary kriging method to interpolate my data: **object name: "dpr.krg"**

```
Simple feature collection with 3885 features and 4 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 848097.3 ymin: 2281812 xmax: 1485685 ymax: 3136914
Projected CRS: NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II + NGF Lallemand height
First 10 features:
           x       y var1.pred   var1.var                       geometry
1  1185538.0 2291408  12.38589 0.03540585 MULTIPOLYGON (((1186108 229...
2  1195629.5 2286807  12.40707 0.03757786 MULTIPOLYGON (((1198097 229...
3  1201101.8 2288814  12.41246 0.03702310 MULTIPOLYGON (((1198097 229...
4   996635.3 2300961  12.14110 0.03187281 MULTIPOLYGON (((998097.3 23...
5  1004070.0 2298689  12.13117 0.02802191 MULTIPOLYGON (((1008097 230...
6  1009703.8 2300029  12.11553 0.02637842 MULTIPOLYGON (((1014797 230...
7  1023116.7 2300258  12.10389 0.02533177 MULTIPOLYGON (((1028097 230...
8  1030446.8 2300867  12.09814 0.02590088 MULTIPOLYGON (((1028097 230...
9  1186016.8 2297043  12.38064 0.02771807 MULTIPOLYGON (((1185004 229...
10 1193204.4 2297477  12.39328 0.02687693 MULTIPOLYGON (((1188097 230...
```

I guess it looks pretty good:

[image]

**FROM HERE MY QUESTION BEGINS!**

I wanted now to aggregate the interpolated data back to couty level using the means of the "nearest feature" or the means of the "intersections", I'm not really sure.

I have tried two approaches with different results.

First I tried this attempt:

```
a1<-st_join(bl.lk,dpr.krg,left=T) %>% 
  aggregate(list(.$var1.pred), mean)

a1

Simple feature collection with 3878 features and 9 fields
Attribute-geometry relationship: 0 constant, 8 aggregate, 1 identity
Geometry type: GEOMETRY
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 848080 ymin: 2281823 xmax: 1485607 ymax: 3136923
Projected CRS: NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II + NGF Lallemand height
First 10 features:
    Group.1      AGS      BMI      dpr psych_dis        x       y var1.pred
1  11.48022 10042.50 26.21000 11.44444  17.92593 923097.3 2486812  11.48022
2  11.48889 10044.00 26.21000 11.44444  17.92593 917522.5 2479905  11.48889
3  11.49469 10042.50 26.21000 11.44444  17.92593 933097.3 2486812  11.49469
4  11.49718 10042.50 26.21000 11.44444  17.92593 923568.2 2477160  11.49718
5  11.50216 10044.00 26.21000 11.44444  17.92593 914425.8 2488008  11.50216
6  11.51038 10041.00 26.21000 11.44444  17.92593 933200.6 2479981  11.51038
7  11.52432 10043.00 26.21175 11.44758  17.93198 923097.3 2496812  11.52432
8  11.53093 10041.00 26.21000 11.44444  17.92593 927361.3 2471509  11.53093
9  11.53557 10041.00 26.21000 11.44444  17.92593 928485.0 2471459  11.53557
10 11.53784 10042.67 26.21042 11.44521  17.92740 933097.3 2496812  11.53784
      var1.var                       geometry
1  0.011184110 POLYGON ((929972.4 2474426,...
2  0.021920620 POLYGON ((933251.2 2507013,...
3  0.008358825 POLYGON ((929972.4 2474426,...
4  0.017955294 POLYGON ((929972.4 2474426,...
5  0.016334040 POLYGON ((933251.2 2507013,...
6  0.011367280 POLYGON ((928068.5 2477750,...
7  0.008089616 POLYGON ((935840.3 2508670,...
8  0.023942613 POLYGON ((928068.5 2477750,...
9  0.023667212 POLYGON ((928068.5 2477750,...
10 0.009007377 POLYGON ((929972.4 2474426,...
```

And my second approach was:

```
a2<-st_join(bl.lk,dpr.krg, left=T) %>%
  group_by(AGS) %>%
  summarise(mean(var1.pred))

names(a2)[names(a2) == "mean(var1.pred)"] <- "var1.pred"

a2
Simple feature collection with 401 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 848080 ymin: 2281823 xmax: 1485607 ymax: 3136923
Projected CRS: NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II + NGF Lallemand height
# A tibble: 401 x 3
     AGS var1.pred                                                    geometry
   <int>     <dbl>                                          <MULTIPOLYGON [m]>
 1  1001      11.7 (((1064024 3116513, 1064892 3115261, 1065097 3113239, 1065~
 2  1002      11.6 (((1111437 3076630, 1112124 3077127, 1113655 3074885, 1114~
 3  1003      11.9 (((1161867 3031796, 1161406 3032579, 1163017 3032765, 1164~
 4  1004      11.6 (((1102924 3044050, 1103845 3044400, 1105259 3043551, 1106~
 5  1051      11.8 (((1058696 3028055, 1058403 3027541, 1059516 3026845, 1059~
 6  1053      12.1 (((1165074 2985679, 1166003 2982501, 1165265 2981093, 1165~
 7  1054      11.8 (((1003984 3083561, 1005616 3084030, 1006873 3081947, 1005~
 8  1055      11.9 (((1149981 3056897, 1149236 3056726, 1149037 3058245, 1150~
 9  1056      11.9 (((1102964 2986154, 1102281 2984642, 1101395 2983211, 1100~
10  1057      11.6 (((1130439 3075640, 1133078 3074357, 1136994 3073664, 1140~
# ... with 391 more rows
```

I'm just intrested for the "var1.pred".

If I plot now both I realised, that I get two different plots and values. So, I'm not sure,if I used the correct approaches. I thought also about using "st_intersect" or "st_nearest_feature" but I'm not sure how to implement those commands into the script.

The plots of **a1 and a2**:

[image]

**I used the following packages: *sf, gstat, tidyverse, automap***

Comment: I think it is more a methodological question than a debugging question. Therefore, I am also grateful for literature that explains conclusively whether this approach of " broad" spatial structures to "finer" structures is possible at all. The problem is that the data collected are only available at the state level, but for the research question the counties are relevant. Unfortunately, I have not found any literature on this subject and would be really grateful for any hints.